# How to check if the command cv2.line has changed the image in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, compare

I have a image (black and white) with a high resolution and I need the information if my drawing command (e.g cv2.line(...)) has changed the image. Comment: There is the probability, that the pixel are already in the color of cv.line(), then the image has not changed.

Currently I am comparing the whole image, whcih is very slow (I have to do this check several 1000 times.)

```
img = LARGE IMAGE
#make copy
imgBuffer= img.copy()
#draw on copy
imgBuffer= cv2.line(imgBuffer, point1, point2, colorBlack, 1);

# calc if there is any difference in the images
diffExist = np.any(cv2.absdiff(drawnImageBuffer, contourImage))
```

Does somebody have an better more efficient idea to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious speed improvement you can make is by only comparing the parts of the image that can possibly have changed by drawing a line connecting your two given points-- the sub-image bounded by the two points that you pass in to cv2.line().

So it would be faster to run:

```
img_buffer = orig_img.copy()
x1, y1 = point1
x2, y2 = point2
# make sure x1 and y1 are the lower values
if x2 < x1:
    x1, x2 = x2, x1
if y2 < y1:
    y1, y2 = y2, y1

cv2.line(img_buffer, point1, point2, colorBlack, 1)

diff_exist = np.any(cv2.absdiff(img_buffer[y1:y2, x1:x2],
                                orig_img[y1:y2, x1:x2]))
```

Comment: This highly improves the speed. Thanks.